# Input greek characters in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, haskell

I used emacs with haskell mode, now I am trying to use the IDE in eclipse with eclipseFP plug-in support, the problem is that eclipse is unable to recognize (nor input) greek characters! So how can I make eclipse to recognize and input greek characters?

Comment: By "recognize" do you mean haskell-mode's pretty formatting that shows "alpha" as "α" and so on, or is this a character encoding issue?

Comment: meant "formatting that shows "alpha" as "α" and so on"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workspace, and each file have an encoding setting - change it to UTF-8 (type "encoding" in the properties dialog)

That said, you should not put greek characters into your code. Use english, and externalize i18nized values.

Comment: Haskell code is assumed to be Unicode, so its not particularly bad.

Comment: @monadic yeah, I've never had a problem with Greek characters in Haskell code. They look nice in type signatures. I've bound a few to keycodes in `vim`; don't know if this is as nice in Eclipse (I would guess one needs to create a custom system keyboard map).

Comment: @monadic The problem is not whether it would work or not (I'm a java developer and it is also unicode). The problem is that the code should be readable. so in general you should avoid any other language/script.

Comment: So, I believe, if the downvotes were because of my advise not to use non-english characters - think code readability. I'm a non-English speaker myself.

Comment: @Bozho I completely agree with you. Many modern languages support Unicode, nevertheless, it always not the best solution to use non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Bozho: In (heavily type-theoretic) Haskell papers Greek characters are often used to represent type variables in function signatures (e.g. `map :: (α → β) → ([α] → [β])`). In some ways it's clearer, since you won't mix up type-level and value-level information :)

Comment: GHC also supports certain unicode symbols as alternate syntax. It's not about internationalization or what language the programmer speaks, it's about mathematical notation, where (among other things) using Greek letters for variables is traditional in some contexts.

Comment: Yes, if you really must, you can do that (I have the solution with setting UTF-8). Just don't overuse it.